# Django Filter based on 2 fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model where I can set expire_date_1 and expire_date_2. And 2 filters like this.

```
filter_1 = Q(expire_date_1__isnull=False) & Q(expire_date_1__lte=after_30days) 
filter_2 = Q(expire_date_2__isnull=False) & Q(expire_date_2__lte=after_30days)
```

I want to filter the model that if expire_date_2 is not null then using filter_2 else use filter_1
I tried it to do with Case and When but I can't filter in a When function, can I?

Comment: Note: `Case` also works in a filter (It is there in the documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to determine what field to use:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.alias(
    exp_date=Coalesce('expire_date_2', 'expire_date_1')
).filter(
    exp_date__lte=after_30_days
)
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) with `.annotate(…)`:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    exp_date=Coalesce('expire_date_2', 'expire_date_1')
).filter(
    exp_date__lte=after_30_days
)
```

Comment: Many thanks Willem Van Onsem ! You saved my day!
I updated it with 2 differents. 
"from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce" - maybe because my django is 2.2
and
"..exp_date=Coalesce('expire_date_2', 'expire_date_1').."  - i want to priority for"expire_date_2"

Comment: @RyanTran: aaarrrgghh yes, you need to swap the parameters. Thanks updated.